# Can I determine if a JSF2 facet is defined in a composite component?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I am creating a JSF2 Facelets composite component.  I would like the HTML to render differently if a particular facet is defined.  Is there any way to check if a `<f:facet name="..." />` has been defined for a composite component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`UIComponent#getFacets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getFacets%28%29) to get a mapping of all facets by their name. So all you need to do is to check if the map value is not empty.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty cc.facets.foo}">
    The facet with name "foo" has been definied for this composite!
</h:panelGroup>
```